# How can I render a video in real time with custom parameters?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rendering, h.264

Is it possible to render a video in real time with custom parameters? I'm trying to *inject* some parameters (text, image and other video portions) into a *video template* depending on user parameters, like the "Facebook 10 Years video"..

The output format should be any video format such as H.264.

I've been googling and asking and the closest I got is to [make a video from HTML5 canvas captures](http://www.ultramegatech.com/2010/09/record-html-canvas-animations-to-video/), which I think is totally inefficient.

Any insight or guidance would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using 3rd party software, this service offers video customization: https://www.impossiblesoftware.com/

I haven't used them but they look promising.